# Video not streaming mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, video

I have no idea why that code doesn't work...
no error message nothing...
thanks

```
<?php require_once('sqlscript.php'); ?>

<?php
$link = mysql_connect('mysql', 'user', 'pass');
if (!$link) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db(database);
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `videos` ORDER BY creation_date desc LIMIT 3';$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo  '<video width="320" height="240" controls> <source src="/upload/'.$row['path'].'"> Your browser does not support the video tag. </video>
  <br />';
    }
mysql_close();
?>
```

[image]

Comment: `var_dump($row);` in while loop, please. What you get?

Comment: you are fetching `$results` in `$row` variable twice!!
1- `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);`
2- `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))`

Comment: @MaveRick nothing to do with the error

Comment: I did var_dump($row) it says null null

Comment: yes but this is just a note that he will lose the first row in his `$result` object when fetching again using the loop `while`

Comment: BTW `creation_date` column is not exist in his table as well

Comment: As a note, posting the results of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` is always better than a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The column `creation_date` is not exist in the table `videos` that will result a syntax error that could be not appearing in the page because you turned off the error displaying
- you have another note here but not related to your issue you called `mysql_fetch_array($result);` before calling it in the loop and that will result loosing the first row in your results of query

Comment: ok i got the creation_date sorted out, how do i do the second thing?

Comment: remove `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);` from your code.
 there is no need to call it before the loop `while`

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything in your database tables?
If there isn't, you would be able to run the script, and it would run without any output or errors.

The mysql query wouldn't fail, and the while loop would never run.

Try putting something like this that checks to see if you get any data returned from your query.

```
var_dump($result);
```

And depending on the output now, as it will print something, even if there isn't any data in your table, people can have an easier time finding problems.

Comment: So aside from the extra mysql_fetch_array() call you have, There is no data being returned from your mysql query. Have you populated your database with either test/real data?

Answer (score 0):

Remove 2 times `fetch_array`, use instead `fetch_assoc` and stop using `mysql_`* since its deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Creation_date doesn't exist.

Try this:

```
<?php require_once('sqlscript.php'); ?>

<?php
$link = mysql_connect('mysql', 'user', 'pass');
if (!$link) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db(database);
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `videos` ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 3';
$result=mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo  '<video width="320" height="240" controls> <source src="/upload/'.$row['path'].'"> Your browser does not support the video tag. </video>
  <br />';
    }
mysql_close();
?>
```